# Angular ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-valid classes not being set

Tags: angular

I am trying to learn Angular and on my first page I have just tried adding a simple form text control.
When its rendered on browser via the command ng serve, i cant see the "ng-pristine, ng-invalid or ng-valid" classes being added.
My html looks like this:

```
<form #form="ngForm" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <div class="input-group-text bg-white">
            <i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input class="form-control" name="UserName" #UserName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.UserName" placeholder="User Name" required />
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have added the bootstrap css in head tag and the required 3 lines of javascript references before the body end tag.

My Angular version

```
Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.900.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.900.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.900.2
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.900.2
@angular-devkit/core              9.0.2
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.0.2
@angular/cli                      9.0.2
@ngtools/webpack                  9.0.2
@schematics/angular               9.0.2
@schematics/update                0.900.2
rxjs                              6.5.4
typescript                        3.7.5
webpack                           4.41.2
```

Comment: Can you share a Stackblitz example?

Comment: Import `import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';` in your `app.module.ts`

Comment: Then add `FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule` in the imports array

Comment: FormsModule was there as I have created the project from Visual Studio standard Angular project. ReactiveFormsModule was not there i have added recompiled still not working.

Comment: i just tested your code that you posted and it works, the problem must be in your ts file or somewhere else. please post more code, or stackblitz even better

Comment: @Lys which version of Angular did you try with? would you pls. send me the entire project as zip

Comment: i hv posted the project on github https://github.com/dannetproject/angular9/tree/master/ClientApp/src/app/home

Comment: i took your html code and placed it in staclblitz and it worked perfectly, open the console and you will see the added classes there. (just make sure no errors in the console from ngModel not knowing your object)